# Getting large data from clipboard

Tags: uwp, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm trying to use the ***Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard*** class available to UWP apps to read content of the clipboard (particularly interested in pasting image data).

Here is my sample code:

```
var clipboardContent = Clipboard.GetContent();
if (clipboardContent.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    var bitmap = await clipboardContent.GetBitmapAsync();
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        var stream = (await bitmap.OpenReadAsync()).AsStream();
        // do something with the data in the stream
    }
}
```

This works fine for relatively small images. But when the image is large then clipboardContent.GetBitmapAsync() will throw an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: The CF_BITMAP format provided by the source app
>   cannot be converted into a stream object.
>
> Additional information: There is insufficient memory available to
>   complete operation.

An example of an image that causes this is http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/79000/79765/dnb_land_ocean_ice.2012.13500x13500.A1.jpg

Even though the image is ~9.5MB, if you open it in a browser and copy it in the clipboard and then try to paste it in a UWP app using the above code then you'll hit the out of memory issue.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I test with your code and the image you provided, it works well in my side. Could you provide some details about your test environment?

Comment: I have a WebView hosting a page with CKEditor + JavaScript in that page that detects paste actions and uses window.external.notify to notify my C# code behind. I then run the above code to load the pasted image data, manipulate it, and then insert it into the CKEditor inside WebView.

I guess it also depends on how much free mem a machine has. I was running on a surface pro device with multiple apps running (including visual studio).

I thought GetBitmapAsync() would allow me to read the clipboard data little chunks at a time no matter how big it is. But it doesn't seem that way!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. I can reproduce this issue when I build with x86 platform and paste multiple times. As the additional information of the exception said, we got this exception because `There is insufficient memory available to complete operation`.

If we use [Diagnostic Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/16/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) while debugging, we can find that when we paste the image you provided, it costs a lot of memory (near 2GB in my side) like following:
[image]

So it's possible that in low memory devices, there is no enough memory to complete the paste operation.

Besides, although the image is only near 9.5 MB, but this is in JPEG format which has been compressed. And this image contains 13500*13500 pixels, if we convert it to BMP format, its size will increase to about 521 MB.

I've reported this issue internally and I will update my answer once there is any progress. For now, I'd suggest you catch this error and give users some prompts. Or if you have control of the copy operation, you can copy with delayed rendering by using [DataPackage.SetDataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdataprovider.aspx) method. As in my test this will significantly reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: You suggest using DataPackage.SetDataProvider. [I tried it (for text) and it doesn't delay the rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50087835/939213). Do you happen to have a solution for that?