# DataPackage.SetDataProvider doesn't wait (unlike its documentation states)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

[DataPackage.SetDataProvider's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdataprovider) states:

> Use the SetDataProvider method when your app ... does not want to
>   supply the data until the target app requests it.

But when I run the following code it calls the callback method immediately.

```
static void CopyToClipboardReference(string s)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    reference = s;
    dataPackage.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Text, CopyToClipboardAction);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
static string reference;
static void CopyToClipboardAction(DataProviderRequest request)
{
    //Called immediately!
    request.SetData(reference);
}
```

When I change `StandardDataFormats.Text` to `StandardDataFormats.Html` it does work as expected (delayed rendering) but then I don't get an option for 'Paste' in applications such as Notepad.

How do I get it to wait for text until it's called from a target app as it is supposed to do according to its documentation?

**Additionally**:

The [DataTransfer.OperationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.operationcompleted) event is not raised.

Comment: If you want to share something from your app, you should use the [DataTransferManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager) class and attach an event handler to the [DataRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.datarequested) event to suply the data.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Thanks. But I want to copy to the clipboard.

Comment: Maybe because clipboard doesn't wait until user pastes. It wants data immediately after you set its content. I'm not sure if Clipboard supports deferred data request (like the way sharing works).

Answer (score 0):

`Clipboard` is a bit different from other sharing options because it is a system-wide feature and it can be used quite anywhere. I imagine that is the reason while the `CopyTOClipboardAction` is executed immediately because the user might want to use the clipboard immediately as well.

This also makes sense, because the user could want to **set the clipboard contents** and then **close the app before pasting**. This really means the data must be there because the system couldn't set the contents later anymore.

Comment: See my edit to my question. It does work with Html etc. I'd like to make it work with text.

Answer (score 0):

As the document [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setdataprovider#remarks) part:

> Use the SetDataProvider method when your app supports a specific format, but does not want to supply the data until the target app requests it.

So if you want to get the content, you should use [DataPackageView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview) Class and use the corresponding method to get it. As a example for the `StandardDataFormats.Html` format,

When you copy the HTML content:

```
static void CopyToClipboardReference(string s)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();

    reference = s;
    dataPackage.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Html, CopyToClipboardAction);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}


static string reference;
static void CopyToClipboardAction(DataProviderRequest request)
{
    //Called immediately!
    request.SetData(reference);
}

private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CopyToClipboardReference("<Html><Body><h1>Load html string.<h1><Body></Html>");
}
```

To get the content, you should call the [DataPackageView.GetHtmlFormatAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.gethtmlformatasync#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackageView_GetHtmlFormatAsync) to get it then the `CopyToClipboardAction` callback will be triggered.

```
async void PasteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
    if (data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Html))
    {
        string htmlFormat = null;
        {
            htmlFormat = await data.GetHtmlFormatAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But as for the `StandardDataFormats.Text` format, the `CopyToClipboardAction` callback will raised twice, I am not sure if it is by design and I will confirm it.

On the other hand, for your issue about the `DataTransfer.OperationCompleted` event is not raised, you can see the detailed answer in your another thread (['OperationCompleted' event not raised after 'Paste' operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100233/operationcompleted-event-not-raised-after-paste-operation)) to call the following code in your paste handler method.

```
dataPackageView.ReportOperationCompleted(DataPackageOperation.Copy);
```

Comment: `as for the StandardDataFormats.Text format, the CopyToClipboardAction callback will raised twice` - I only noticed once, immediately. If there's a way for it to be called twice (once immediately, and once on 'paste') that would solve the problem.

Comment: @ispiro, it seems that using the delay-render works different between text and html, could you please submit this issue in our Windows 10 Feedback Hub app and share the link in here? After that I can involve the related team to look at this issue and you can keep monitor the status of this issue in our Feedback Hub.