# 'OperationCompleted' event not raised after 'Paste' operation

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

The `OperationCompleted` event is supposed to be raised at the end of a Clipboard Paste operation as mentioned in [DataPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage):

> OperationCompleted    Occurs when a paste operation is completed.

It's not.

Why? / What's a workaround?

**Code**:

```
static void CopyToClipboard(string s)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.SetText(s);
    dataPackage.OperationCompleted += DataPackage_OperationCompleted1;
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
}
static void DataPackage_OperationCompleted1(DataPackage sender, OperationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `Remarks` section on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.operationcompleted).

> This event occurs when a user or program pastes content from the Clipboard. If your app is using the DataPackage for share operations, you do not have to handle this event.

Then, in your paste handler method, you would need to use `dataPackageView.ReportOperationCompleted()` method to inform the system that your app is finished using the DataPackageView object.

I used the official [Clipboard](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Clipboard/cs/CopyText.xaml.cs) code sample to test.

In this [line](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Clipboard/cs/CopyText.xaml.cs#L114), I added the following code:

```
dataPackageView.ReportOperationCompleted(DataPackageOperation.Copy);
```

After that, the DataPackage's OperationCompleted event would be fired.